# addslashes() no slashes when inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason addslashes is NOT adding slashes when inserting data into database. I thought I was using this right, but clearly not... When I submit data that has single or double quotes, it is just sending the exact string right in. Any ideas on how to make this work?

#### The code

```
<?php
//include db connect
  include ("db_con.php");

//start session
  session_start();

//set variable names
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $entry = addslashes($_POST['entry']);
  $uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

//send chat
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO chat (username, entry) VALUES
                                                ('".$username."', '".$entry."')"); 
  if ($query) {
    header('Location: '. $uri);
  } else {
    echo 'Chat entry failed for an unknown reason - Please go back and try again';
  }
?>
```

Comment: [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) is not the correct function for escaping data when entering into databases, as its manual page clearly states. The correct function in this case is [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: addslashes is about as useful for protection against sql injection attacks as wet toilet paper is as a rope. Try to forget the function even exists and NEVER use it for anything.

Answer (score 2):

`addslashes()` is for escaping the string. If you got code:

```
$lastname = "O'Bama";

$query = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE lastname='$lastname'";
```

The query will produce an error because `Bama` will be treated as SQL statement. To prevent this you can use `addslashes()` so

```
echo addslashes($lastname); // returns O\'Bama
```

Now you can execute your query without any errors because your database will see value as "O'Bama".

Comment: So you are saying that `addslashes()` may be doing it's job, however it still will insert it into the database with the quotes? or am I totally misunderstanding you?

Comment: It will insert quotes because you are escaping them and they are not treated as part of SQL query but part of your value.

Comment: Ok so this should help secure against SQL injections correct? Sorry for the newby questions, I am still a PHP/MySQL beginner.

Comment: Correction, [`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) is **not** for doing anything with databases. The correct function in this case is [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @Aldentec No, this is not nearly enough to prevent SQL injection. For proper security you should use PDO with parameterized queries: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php or MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

Using `addslashes()` when dealing with databases is very bad practice. Since you're using PHP's mysqli extension, you should escape your data with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. The PHP manual page for `addslashes()` explains why.